# How to Refresh my Mobile data network in android current version?

Tags: android

Kindly give answer,i have trouble to refresh mobile network,I don't want system app,I need only for android Mobile apps,I need to refresh my mobile data network pro grammatically in current version like marshmallow and nougat,I already put permissions for this,i attached following my codes

```
private static boolean setMobileConnectionEnabled(Context context, boolean enabled) {
    try {
        // Requires: android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
            Log.i("if", "" + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);
            // pre-Gingerbread sucks!
            final TelephonyManager telMgr = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            final Method getITelephony = telMgr.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
            getITelephony.setAccessible(true);
            final Object objITelephony = getITelephony.invoke(telMgr);
            final Method toggleDataConnectivity = objITelephony.getClass()
                    .getDeclaredMethod(enabled ? "enableDataConnectivity" : "disableDataConnectivity");
            toggleDataConnectivity.setAccessible(true);
            toggleDataConnectivity.invoke(objITelephony);
        }
        // Requires: android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE
        else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Log.i("else", "" + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);
            final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            // Gingerbread to KitKat inclusive
            final Field serviceField = connMgr.getClass().getDeclaredField("mService");
            serviceField.setAccessible(true);
            final Object connService = serviceField.get(connMgr);
            try {
                final Method setMobileDataEnabled = connService.getClass()
                        .getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", Boolean.TYPE);
                Log.i("try", "" + setMobileDataEnabled);
                setMobileDataEnabled.setAccessible(true);
                setMobileDataEnabled.invoke(connService, Boolean.valueOf(enabled));
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                // Support for CyanogenMod 11+
                final Method setMobileDataEnabled = connService.getClass()
                        .getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", String.class, Boolean.TYPE);
                setMobileDataEnabled.setAccessible(true);
                Log.i("catch", "" + setMobileDataEnabled);
                Log.i("errr", "" + e.getMessage());
                try {
                    setMobileDataEnabled.invoke(connService, context.getPackageName(), Boolean.valueOf(enabled));
                } catch (InvocationTargetException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        // Requires: android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE (System only, here for completions sake)
        else {
            // Lollipop and into the Future!
            final TelephonyManager telMgr = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            Log.i("telMgr",""+telMgr);
            final Method setDataEnabled = telMgr.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setDataEnabled", Boolean.TYPE);
            Log.i("telMgdfgsdgr",""+setDataEnabled);
            setDataEnabled.setAccessible(true);
            setDataEnabled.invoke(telMgr, Boolean.valueOf(enabled));
        }
        return true;
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        Log.e("", "setMobileConnectionEnabled", e);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        Log.e("gsdjkghskd", "setMobileConnectionEnabled", e);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        Log.e("lllll", "setMobileConnectionEnabled", e);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        Log.e("nooooo", "setMobileConnectionEnabled", e);
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        Log.e("innnnnn", "setMobileConnectionEnabled", e);
    }
    return false;
}
```

My Manifest file

```
<permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="24" />
<permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
    android:maxSdkVersion="24" />

<permission
    android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="24" />

<permission
    android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="24" />
```

Kindly give some suggestions please

Comment: hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you please let us know what do you actually mean by "Refresh my data network"?

Comment: I mean Mobile Network sir.

Comment: I already put runtime permission also but it showing error like this     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10227 nor current process has android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE. I got error like this

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so I'll put my answer here, but it might disappoint you.

There's currently no way to do that in Android >= 5.

You can do that only on rooted phone or system app. It was possible through reflection but since it was @Hide annotated Google removed it and had every right to do so.

If you're looking for disabling only (or disabling the the possibility to change cellular data state) you can use your device provider's api (like Samsung). Samsung allows to disable the possibility to change the cell data state, but... you cannot force the state back to on, after the possibility to change was turned off.

Google repeatedly ignores tickets from the community to bring back this option to SDK.

Please downvote this answer only if you have a solution how to do that without rooted phone or system app.